# R Shiny ReactiveUI

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working on a project in R Shiny that can do certain data analysis tasks. I'm trying to add the ability for users to upload their own data sets for use with the tool. One of the main features of this tool is the ability to filter the data set based on different components of the data. Obviously, this requires altering the UI based on the contents of the data set. I tried to do this with some code that looks similar to the below, but only the "season" checkbox group shows up when I run it, not the "name1" or "name2" drop-down menus, and not the "site" checkbox group.

**ui.R**

```
fluidPage(tabsetPanel(
  tabPanel(title="Upload data",
      fileInput(inputId = "updata", label = "Upload your own data to use with the webapp:", accept = ".csv"),
      div("Once the file has finished uploading, press the button below:"),
      actionButton(inputId = "dataButton", label="Generate dataset from uploaded file")
  )
  tabPanel(title="Filter data",
    uiOutput("speciesUI")
  )
))
```

**server.R**

```
function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(eventExpr = input$dataButton, handlerExpr = {
    ind.data <<- read.table(file = tail((input$updata)$datapath, n=1),, sep=",")

     output$"speciesUI" <- renderUI({
        namelist <<- names(table(ind.data$Species))
        selectInput(inputId = "name1", label="Choose the first species:", choices=namelist)
        selectInput(inputId = "name2", label="Choose the second species:", choices=namelist)

        sitelist <<- names(table(ind.data$Site))
        checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "sites", label="Filter by site(s)",   choices=sitelist, selected=sitelist)

        seasonlist <<- names(table(ind.data$Season))
        checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "seasons", label="Filter by season(s)", choices=seasonlist, selected=seasonlist)
     })
  }
}
```

.

### **What do I need to do differently in order to get the missing UI elements (name1, name2, and sites) to appear after loading a data set?**

Basically, I just want the user to be able to upload their data set and click a button in the first tab, and then filter through the data set using controls in the second tab.

Comment: Prefer using `reactiveValues` instead of `<<-`

Comment: The last expression of the code block is what is returned... which is the `checkboxGroupInput`

Comment: Use `output$speciesUI` instead of `output$"speciesUI"`

Comment: Remove the `renderUI` from the `observeEvent`, and trigger it with `reactiveValues`

Comment: And create one `renderUI` per input or put them all inside a `div`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments by @HubertL, I figured out the following answer:

The code block only returns the last statement by default. Wrap all the reactive UI elements in a `div()` in order to make sure it returns all the UI elements, rather than just the last one.

One edit to server.R fixed the issue, so now it looks like this:

```
output$"speciesUI" <- renderUI({
      namelist <<- names(table(ind.data$Species))
      sitelist <<- names(table(ind.data$Site))
      seasonlist <<- names(table(ind.data$Season))

      div(
        selectInput(inputId = "name1", label="Choose the first species:", choices=namelist),
        selectInput(inputId = "name2", label="Choose the second species:", choices=namelist),
        checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "sites", label="Filter by site(s)", choices=sitelist, selected=sitelist),
        checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "seasons", label="Filter by season(s)", choices=seasonlist, selected=seasonlist)
      )
    })
```

Comment: if `namelist, sitelist and seasonlist` are no used somewhere else in the code, just use regular assignment `<-` to create local variables